# Why Hull in Blink?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Dr Who episode 'Blink' Kath Nightingale is zapped back in time by the Weeping Angels and ends up in a meadow near Hull.

Is there anything in canon that explains why Hull?

Comment: Probably because of all the [fantastic restaurants](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43Ij7lcSiNs).

Comment: I expect the script said "Hell" and there was a typo

Comment: @PaulD.Waite or the [great university](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKuHYO9TM5A)

Comment: Why not Hull? Is there something that seems _wrong_ about Hull?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weeping Angels can send people back through time *and* space, and evidently, they can choose to do one, or the other, or both.

- In *Blink*, Billy, was sent back in time but *not space*, as he was still in the police station garage where he encountered an angel.
- Kath Nightingale was sent through time *and* space as you pointed out.
- In *The Angels Take Manhattan*, an Angel sends Rory through space but *not time* when he is moved from Grayle's mansion to the Winter Quay apartments.

It transpired that the instance of Rory being moved through space only was so that his energy could be 'farmed' in his new location instead of just taken by the angel that caught him, so it is clearly a conscious choice on the part of the angel where and when to send somebody.

There doesn't seem to be any specific reason that Kath was sent to Hull, of all places, but it seems reasonable to assume that the angels based at Wester Drumlins might have sent all their victims to random places to ensure that they did not all go to the same place and time. We know that many people disappeared from Wester Drumlins, where Kath was caught, as all the cars in the police basement garage had been recovered from the house there. The Doctor and Martha had also been caught there, as Billy explained to Sally that is also where the TARDIS had been recovered from. It is never mentioned *where* The Doctor and Martha were sent to other than back to 1969. But if all the people sent back in time from Wester Drumlins had gone to the same place then The Doctor would probably have met up with those first. It may have been intentional on the part of the angels based at Wester Drumlins to send their victims to different places in order to keep them apart and lessen the chance of them figuring out what was going on. We have to assume that The Doctor and Martha made their way back to the area from wherever they ended up as part of their mission to recover the TARDIS, and that the Doctor used his 'Timey-Wimey Detector' to locate the underground basement where they found Billy after his displacement in time.

So, it would seem that Billy being sent back in time *only* was actually the exception. Perhaps the reason for this is that he was the victim of an impromptu attack by an angel trying to get at the TARDIS, rather than part of an organised operation such as at Wester Drumlins or the Winter Quay apartments in Manhattan.

The choice of Hull as the only place that we hear of any victim being sent to seems entirely meta and nothing to do with internal Doctor Who canon. It was most likely chosen by Steven Moffat because of his comedy sensibilities. In *Time Crash*, he wrote that a hole in the space-time continuum was the size of Belgium, the humour coming from the fact that the place was "undramatic". Kathy's surprise at being in Hull definitely has the same element of humour about it - going from the country's capital to Yorkshire's fourth largest city is somewhat undramatic, and the very fact you're wondering '*why Hull*' backs that up.

Comment: Your answer raises the question of _why_ the Angels might care if they sent 100 people back to the same time/place then they all got together and figured out what happened. What the heck would they do about it if they knew? Unless, of course, one of them happened to be The Doctor or maybe River Song...

Comment: @FreeMan Divide and conquer is a fairly common strategy. But that's only a possibility. The Doctor suggested that Billy was sent back to roughly the same *time* as he and Martha had because they'd been touched by the same angel, but not necessarily the same *place* because the doctor hadn't been hanging round the car park, he'd used his device to find Billy. Perhaps the location was just random even if the time wasn't. Either way, nothing points to Hull being special in-universe.

Comment: Yeah, but what could mere mortals do against the Angels even if they knew what had happened to them? I guess 100 people could take shifts to keep the angels frozen, but they'd still never be able to get back to their own time/place. Oh well... `</off-topic>`

Comment: @freeman You say that, but in 'Blink' the Doctor did nothing to the angels. Humans defeated the angels and rescued the Doctor. The only help the Doctor gave them was in the effort to rescue him - the angels were caught out inadvertently. No, they couldn't get back to their own time but Billy did live long enough to speak to Sally so if enough of them had joined forces to figure out what was going on it is reasonable to say they could have got instructions to those left in the future in a less convoluted way than the Doctor sent his message.